# For Loop in React Native Render Method

Tags: react-native, for-loop

I am trying to pass several arrays through a for loop in the render method and render that data with View. I keep getting an error in sentry.io "undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.number[o]')"

I am pretty new to this and any help would be appreciated!

```js
render() {
  const userInfo = this.state.userInfo;
  const thisArray = this.state.thisArray;
  var myloop = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const totals = thisArray[i].number;
    const yourNumber = userInfo.number[i].enrolledNumber;
    myloop.push(
      <View key={i}>
        <Separator />
        <Text style={[styles.content, { fontSize: 20 }]}>
          {thisArray[i].name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.txtColor}>Data</Text>
          {myloop}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I am getting the following error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'thisArray[i].number')

Does anyone have thoughts?

Comment: add full component code

Comment: Check the `thisArray.length`. Your `thisArray` doesn't have an index 1 or 2.

Comment: It has an index at 0,1,2.

Comment: I've added the full component code. It works in development mode in Expo but fails in Expo Production mode.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I passed the items through a flat list as such:

```
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.thisArray}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          />
```

then I called it through a renderItem method

```
renderItem = ({ item}) => {

    return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{item.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{item.id}</Text>
        </View>
)
}
```

Thanks guys,